# Show SignUp Activity of my android app only once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to know how to skip the signup activity of android app with Firebase and I want to show it only on first time running of app.
I need only the signup activity whenever the user open the app for second time, he need to be logged in and should redirected to my other activity.

my signup activity is

```
    package com.example.a963fa.ambigo;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword;

    private static Button button_signup;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuthListner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuthListner = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuthListner = (FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)(firebaseAuth){

        }

        findViewById(R.id.Button_signup).setOnClickListener(this);

        onClickButtonListener();

    }

    public void onClickButtonListener(){

        button_signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_signup);
        button_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.a963fa.ambigo.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

private void registerUser(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()){
        editTextEmail.setError("E-mail is required");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){

        editTextEmail.setError("Please enter a valid E-mail");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.isEmpty()){
        editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.length()<6){
        editTextPassword.setError("Minimum Length of password should be 6");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You already registered with this E-mail and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

                registerUser();
    }

}
```

please help me with step by step procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that user is logged in or not by -

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
```

This will return `null` if user is not logged in.

Comment: please tell me where in my java file, i should add this.

Comment: and mention if any variable or method declarations required

Comment: i expect a step by step procedure from you sir

Comment: @mfkmedia, Please add this check in onCreate and if user is not null the start your main activity

Answer (score 0):

If there is a splash screen then check in the splash screen whether FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() is null or not and then start the intent accordingly.

And if you are not using splash screen then in the launching activity in onCreate(), check for the same.